# How can I add some items to an array based on a condition?

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, pdo

I have these two queries:

```
$db
->prepare("UPDATE users 
            SET reputation = reputation + (CASE id  WHEN ? THEN 2 WHEN ? THEN 15 END),
                Money      = Money      + (CASE id  WHEN ? THEN ? WHEN ? THEN ?  END)
            WHERE id IN (?, ?); ")
->execute(array($author_ques_id, $author_ans_id, 
                $author_ques_id, $asker_amount, $author_ans_id, $responder_amount,
                $author_ans_id, $author_ques_id));


$db
->prepare("INSERT INTO events (type, score, post_id, table_code, user_id, author_id, date_time )
                       VALUES (4   , 2    , ?      , 15        , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ),
                              (4   , 15   , ?      , 15        , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ),
                              (5   , ?    , ?      , 15        , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ),
                              (5   , ?    , ?      , 15        , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )")
->execute(array($answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id,
                $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ans_id,
                $asker_amount, $ques_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id,
                $responder_amount, $answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ans_id));
```

Those two queries above should be correct when this condition is true:

```
if ( $author_ques_id != $author_ans_id ) {
    // then queries above are fine
} else {
    // queries should be like below
}
```

As I commented in the condition above, if that condition is *false*, then those two queries should be like these:

```
$db
->prepare("UPDATE users 
            SET reputation = reputation + 2,
                Money      = Money      + ?
            WHERE id ?; ")
->execute(array($asker_amount,
                $author_ques_id));


$db
->prepare("INSERT INTO events (type, score, post_id, table_code, user_id, author_id, date_time )
                       VALUES (4   , 2    , ?      , 15        , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ),
                              (5   , ?    , ?      , 15        , ?      , ?        , UNIX_TIMESTAMP() )")
->execute(array($answer_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id,
                $asker_amount, $ques_id, $author_ques_id, $author_ques_id));
```

Ok, All I want to know, should I write those queries twice for each cases? Or can I create a dynamic query based on that condition?

Comment: This is getting messy in a hurry. Are you sure there's no way to do this without leaning on the `CASE` statement so heavily? A series of simple `UPDATE` statements inside a transaction is is usually better than a convoluted chunk of SQL like this.

Answer (score 0):

Your queries are quite different, so keep them seperated and write them for each case, at least the update statements.

For the inserts you could define the values in your if-else and write them into arrays and then iterate over the array to insert one row after the other. Like this

```
if($x ===true){
    $update = "....";
    $values = array(array(1,"b",3,4), array(5,6,7,8));
}else{
    $update = "....";
    $values = array(array(0,0,"c",6));
}
$insert = $pdo->prepare('INTO table (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
foreach($values as $row){
    $insert->execute($row);
}
```